# Python3で、改行のある複数の文字列を「input」したいです

Tags: python, python3

Python3　で、改行のある複数の文字列を「input」したいです。

例えば、「りんご」、「みかん」という文字列が改行され、標準入力された場合、これを、それぞれ「a」と「b」という変数に代入したいです。できれば、標準入力が3つ以上ある場合、また、これらを一行で表す方法も知りたいです。

(標準入力)
りんご<kbd>return</kbd>みかん<kbd>return</kbd>

(処理結果)
変数 a に「りんご」を代入
変数 b に「みかん」を代入

Answer (score 5):

組み込み関数 `input()` で標準入力を 1 行取ってこれます。

```
a = input()
b = input()
```

入力される個数が何個か分からないとき（個数が可変のとき）は、`input()` を繰り返し行いつつ、データをリストに保存すると良いでしょう。このとき繰り返しの終了条件を決めておく必要があります。

たとえば入力の終了 [EOF](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_Of_File) まで読み続けるのであれば、以下のように書けます。

```
lines = []
while True:
    try:
        lines.append(input())
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: `line = input(); if not line.strip():break` could work